# Devise user edit registration path not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, authorization

I have a rails 4 app that has a User model, and two types of Users: lenders and businesses. On sign in, lenders are directed to their dashboard which shows them information about their businesses. From the dashboard they can goto their 'Account' page which is where they can edit their information (password, email etc.)

When the user selects 'Account' a devise message is displayed that says:

```
You need to sign in or sign up before continuing.
```

At this point, the user has already been authenticated and the dashboard accesses the user's attributes with @user.name and other calls in the view that would require the user to be authenticated.

I need to figure out why the edit_lender_registration_path isn't accepting the currently authenticated user.

**routes.rb**

```
devise_for :users, skip: :registrations
devise_for :lenders, skip: :sessions, :controllers => {:registrations => "lenders/registrations"}
devise_for :businesses, skip: :sessions, :controllers => {:registrations => "businesses/registrations"}
```

**_sidebar.html.erb**

```
<li class="list-group-item">
  <%= link_to edit_lender_registration_path do %>
    <i class="fa fa-user"></i> Account
  <% end %>
</li>
```

**registrations_controller.rb**

```
class Lenders::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_filter :update_sanitized_params

  def new
    super
    flash[:success] = 'An email has been sent to your inbox with a link to activate you account.'
  end

  def create
    super
  end

  def update
    super
  end

  private

  def update_sanitized_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) {|u| u.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :type, :confirmed_at)}
  end
end
```

Comment: Are users, lenders and businesses different models?

Comment: @mus lenders and businesses are different models but they inherit from user.

Comment: My guess is that `devise_for :lenders` automagically requires `Lender` to be signed in. And you're using `devise_for :users` to create sessions. Try removing `skip: :sessions`, then sign_in using the lenders' path and see if that works.